# Add a label with the input placeholder

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add the label with the content of the placeholder with jQuery.
But I don't understand the reason it generates me a lot of labels as if the cycle were not closed or stopped only after something else

this is my **html before**

```
<div class="column one">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nome">
<input type="text" placeholder="Nome e Cognome*" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">
</span>
</div>
```

this is **html after**:

```
<div class="column one">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nome">
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required resizedFontJQ" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Nome e Cognome*" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">
    </span> 
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
    <label class="addedLabel">Nome e Cognome*</label>
</div>
```

The **jQuery** i used:

```
jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").each( function () {
      var inputTextLabel= jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").attr("placeholder")
      jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").closest("div").append("<label class='addedLabel'>" + inputTextLabel + "</label>");
    });
```

Comment: Where does the **.wpcf7** class coming from in your jQuery selector? You don't have it in the code you posted.

Comment: You should write the HTML correctly in the first place. `<label>` and `placeholder` are not interchangeable and shouldn't have the same content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your logic.

For **each** of the elements that match your selector, you are appending some HTML to **everything** that matches `jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").closest("div")`.

You need to pay attention to the specific element each time you go around the loop.

```
jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").each( function (index, element) {
  var $element = $(element);
  var inputTextLabel= $element.attr("placeholder")
  $element.closest("div").append("<label class='addedLabel'>" + inputTextLabel + "</label>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="column one">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nome">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome e Cognome*" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">
  </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(".wpcf7 .column input").each( function () {
  var inputTextLabel= jQuery( this ).attr("placeholder")
  jQuery(this).closest("div").append("<label class='addedLabel'>" + inputTextLabel + "</label>");
});
```